# How to work with Alert Dialog Boxes in OnDraw method In Android

Tags: android, multithreading, ondraw

Hi i want to use alert dialog box in OnDraw method in a game which is called again and again by a thread.I am unable to do this. The screen start flickering. There is no error in the alert box because its working outside the OnDraw method. A little help will be highly appreciated if any one would like to help me.
I want to use the alert box in OnDraw method which is called again n again.

thanks
all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply get a boolean to keep track of whether the dialog is visible?

```
if(!dialogVisible && wantDialog)
{
    //do whatever you need to show the dialog and everything
    dialogVisible = true;
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I have already tried this....but result is the same.....the screen flickers. I actually know the problem but i cant find a perfect solution. I have a solution but its not professional. Actually in OnDraw method there are man images that are drawn again n again. Which makes alert box to flicker.Thanks for your help but unfortunately this is not the solution.